# How to perform imputations on a variable given the number of occurrences of values for the same variable?

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to perform imputations on a variable such that it is constant within each `id`. That is  `var1` can only have one distinct value for each and every `id`.

One of it is to perform imputations given the number of occurrences of values of an existing variable as well as some other conditions.

```
df_old<- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
date       id  var1 
25/01/2016  1  A 
02/05/2016  1  A 
20/03/2016  1  B 
13/07/2016  1  NA
20/03/2016  2  B 
28/04/2016  2  C
20/03/2016  3  B 
28/04/2016  3  OTHERS
28/04/2016  3  OTHERS 
20/10/2016  4  NA 
28/11/2016  4  NA
",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

We focus on `var1` here. Within each `id`:

1. If `var1` has either `A`, `B` or `C`, then we impute `var1` with the value that occurs the most. e.g. for `id=1`, it has two distinct `var1` values (`A` and `B`), hence we impute it with `A` since it occurs the most. Impute the missing value with `A` also.
2. If `var1` has either `A`, `B` or `C`, and the two distinct `var1` values have the same number of occurrences, then we impute the `var1` value with the one that occurs the latest. For `id=2`, it has one `B` and one `C`. We impute it with `C` since the date corresponding to it occurs the lastest.
3. If `var1` contains two distinct values one of it is either `A`/`B`/`C` and the other is `OTHERS`, we always impute using `A`/`B`/`C`. Hence, for `id=3` we impute using `B` instead of `OTHERS`.
4. If `var1` contains only `OTHERS`, then it will remain as `OTHERS`.
5. For `id=4` where it does not have any `var1` values, they will remain as missing values.

Hence, new dataframe should look like:

```
df_new<- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
date       id  var1 
25/01/2016  1  A 
02/05/2016  1  A 
20/03/2016  1  A 
13/07/2016  1  A
20/03/2016  2  C 
28/04/2016  2  C
20/03/2016  3  B 
28/04/2016  3  B
28/04/2016  3  B 
20/10/2016  4  NA 
28/11/2016  4  NA
",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`
```

I have tried to write out the first case, but I can't seem to solve it and hence cannot move on with the other cases.

```
library(dplyr)
df_old %>%
group_by(id,var1) %>%
mutate(n=n()) %>%
group_by(id) %>%
mutate(var1=if_else(n==min(n),var1[max(n)],var1[max(n)]))
```

or replace the last line with 
`replace(var1,which(min(n)),var1[which(max(n))]))`

Both give errors:

> Error: invalid 'type' (closure) of argument"

How do I rectify this?

Comment: What if the group contains only `OTHERS`? Should the new variable be `OTHERS`?

Comment: @Psidom Yes, I would want it to remain as `OTHERS`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `tidyverse` functions as:

```
dft %>% 
      group_by(id, var1) %>%
      mutate(var2 = n()) %>%
      mutate(var2 = if_else(var1 == "OTHERS", as.integer(0), as.integer(var2))) %>%
      mutate( var2 = if_else( is.na(var2), as.integer(-1), as.integer(var2))) %>%
      ungroup() %>%
      group_by(id) %>%
      arrange(desc(date)) %>%
      mutate(var3 = var1[which.max(var2)]) %>%
      arrange(id) %>%
      select(date, id, var3)
```

which gives:

```
Source: local data frame [11 x 3]
Groups: id [4]

         date    id  var3
        <chr> <int> <chr>
1  25/01/2016     1     A
2  20/03/2016     1     A
3  13/07/2016     1     A
4  02/05/2016     1     A
5  28/04/2016     2     C
6  20/03/2016     2     C
7  28/04/2016     3     B
8  28/04/2016     3     B
9  20/03/2016     3     B
10 28/11/2016     4  <NA>
11 20/10/2016     4  <NA>
```

---

We used 0 and -1 to account for frequencies of `OTHERS` and `NA`. If you prefer a different priority order, change the values accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, this is great! I guess assigning numbers like `0` for `OTHERS` and `-1` for `NA` makes computations easier. Also, I thought since you can't arrange dates within each group ( https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/2116 ), I thought it would be better to arrange by `id` then by `desc(date)` before grouping by `id`. For e.g. `arrange(id,desc(date)) %>% group_by(id)`.